# Office 365 Profile picture are not updated in user profile in office 365

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365

I have admin account in Office 365 site. 
I have updated my profile picture by going this URL

https://portal.office.com/account/#personalinfo

But when I'm trying to get that picture from user profile that time it display default picure of SharePoint for user profile.
Picture not get updated in office 365 admin center user profiles.

But when I'm login  as site user that time it shows image in ribbon on right site corner.

[image]

Comment: Please clear your browser's cache, it may help.

Comment: It´s maybe can delay until one week..

Answer (score 2):

SPO takes around 72 hours to update the picture.
For more go to link below:
https://spbreed.wordpress.com/2015/11/06/demystifying-user-profile-picture-sync-in-office365/